# Linux updating, downloading [Awaiting headers]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I've installed fresh CentOS and I've been having problems updating, downloading as it always either gave me an error "Trying other mirror" + "Read error (connection timed out) in headers". Then I tried to install Ubuntu Server and the same problem, here it says "100% [Awaiting headers]"... when trying to update or download something. There were few exceptions though when manual WGET downloads were successful, but very rare. To note, APACHE was working fine as I've been able to access the web page from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a firewall issue - sounds like your Linux servers aren't allowed to do DNS, HTTP and HTTPS into the internet.

Comment: Thanks, what could be causing that? I disabled UFW, Iptables and its still the same.